# Listen to mouse event of a child element that the directive attached to - Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

Can I listen to mouse events that occurs only inside the child of the element that the directive attached to with @HostListner()?

```
<div listnerDirective class="parent">
   <div class="child> <------ listen to mouse event
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And why cant you apply the directive to the child ?

Comment: @dota2pro Its a dynamically created SVG element

Comment: Just add simple event listener to the element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event']) onMouseClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
  // Check for child
  if ( !event.target.classList.contains('parent') ) {
    // Click happened on child
    // Child click code here
  }
}
```